# TableData.insertAll with templateSuffix - frequent 503 errors

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using TableData.insertAll with a templateSuffix and are experiencing frequent 503 errors with our usage pattern.

We set the templateSuffix based on two pieces of information - the name of the event being inserted and the data of the event being inserted. E.g. 'NewPlayer20160712'. The table ID is set to 'events'.

In most cases this works as expected, but relatively often it will fail and return an error. Approximately 1 in every 200 inserts will fail, which seems way too often for expected behaviour.

The core of our event ingestion service looks like this:

```
//Handle all rows in rowsBySuffix
async.mapLimit(Object.keys(rowsBySuffix), 5, function(suffix) {
    //Construct request for suffix
    var request = {
        projectId: "tactile-analytics",
        datasetId: "discoducksdev",
        tableId: "events",
        resource: {
            "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
            "skipInvalidRows": true,
            "ignoreUnknownValues": true,
            "templateSuffix": suffix, // E.g. NewPlayer20160712
            "rows": rowsBySuffix[suffix]
        },
        auth: jwt // valid google.auth.JWT instance
    };

    //Insert all rows into BigQuery
    var cb = arguments[arguments.length-1];
    bigquery.tabledata.insertAll(request, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error insertAll. err=" + JSON.stringify(err) + ", request.resource=" + JSON.stringify(request.resource));
        }
        cb(err, result);
    });
}, arguments[arguments.length-1]);
```

A typical error would look like this:

```
{
   "code": 503,
   "errors": [
      {
         "domain": "global",
         "reason": "backendError",
         "message": "Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem."
      }
   ]
}
```

The resource part for the insertAll that fails looks like this:

```
 {
   "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
   "skipInvalidRows": true,
   "ignoreUnknownValues": true,
   "templateSuffix": "GameStarted20160618",
   "rows": [
      {
         "insertId": "1f4786eaccd1c16d7ce865fea4c7af89",
         "json": {
            "eventName": "gameStarted",
            "eventSchemaHash": "unique-schema-hash-value",
            "eventTimestamp": 1466264556,
            "userId": "f769dc78-3210-4fd5-a2b0-ca4c48447578",
            "sessionId": "821f8f40-ed08-49ff-b6ac-9a1b8194286b",
            "platform": "WEBPLAYER",
            "versionName": "1.0.0",
            "versionCode": 12345,
            "ts_param1": "2016-06-04 00:00",
            "ts_param2": "2014-01-01 00:00",
            "i_param0": 598,
            "i_param1": 491,
            "i_param2": 206,
            "i_param3": 412,
            "i_param4": 590,
            "i_param5": 842,
            "f_param0": 5945.442,
            "f_param1": 1623.4111,
            "f_param2": 147.04747,
            "f_param3": 6448.521,
            "b_param0": true,
            "b_param1": false,
            "b_param2": true,
            "b_param3": true,
            "s_param0": "Im guesior ti asorne usse siorst apedir eamighte rel kin.",
            "s_param1": "Whe autiorne awayst pon, lecurt mun.",
            "eventHash": "1f4786eaccd1c16d7ce865fea4c7af89",
            "collectTimestamp": "1468346812",
            "eventDate": "2016-06-18"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

We have noticed that, if we avoid including the name of the event in the suffix (e.g. the NewPlayer part) and instead just have the date as the suffix, then we never experience these errors.

Is there any way that this can be made to work reliably?

Answer (score 1):

Backend errors happen, we usually see 5 from 10000 requests. We simply retry, and we have more constant rate, and we can provide a reconstructable use case we put a ticket on the Bigquery issue tracker. This way if there is something wrong with our project it can be investigated.

https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/